# Performant for bulk insert of objects with child objects

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, c#-4.0

I am currently in a struggle here.

**Environment:**
I am *improving* an application in C# 4.0 wit MSSQL Server 2008 R2.
I am not using any type of ORM.

**Design/Model:** (Fictive) I have a Conversation, a message, and a attachment. The conversation has multiple messages, each message can have multiple attachments. So easy 1 .. N connections over there.

**The problem:** I would like to store into my DB a new conversation, with new conversation messages and new attachments. My situation right now is that I go top-down by saving the conversation. Retrieve that id, set that id to the message objects and store the messages (every time I do separate db calls). And same story again for all the attachments, I need first to store the message before I can store these attachments.

**My solutions I looked into or have in mind**

- Currently I do these steps individual, top-down saving mechanism through Stored Procedures.
- SqlBulkCopy : Really fast. I had in mind, store all conversations, get Ids back, store all messages, get their ids back etc... But the issues is here, I need to do a query like "Give me all 20 last created records their id". Doable, but the fact that this application is multithreaded it might be that in that moment other threads would have inserted new rows or worse, deleted.
- Create Stored Procedure a crazy stored procedure where I send in a dataset object (this is more free brainstorming thing).
- Manually generate a huge sql command that stores a conversation, gets the generated id, and uses that for the child objects. Like (pseudo SQL):

  INSERT conversation

  currentConversationId = @Identity

  INSERT message with conversationId = currentConversationId

**Goal**
Does someone have better suggestions or alternatives. Please avoid advising me to go to an ORM because I am working with a legacy project. I would like to SAVE DB calls as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use table-values parameters to send multiple rows to insert in one call. You can use the `OUTPUT INSERTED.ID` clause to retrieve the ids that were created. When using the `MERGE` statement you can not only retrieve the IDs but also the original values from your TVP. That is useful to match the IDs to TVP rows. That could look something like this:

```
OUTPUT @tvp.SomeID, INSERTED.ID
```

Comment: From what I understood from the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). First note "You cannot return data in a table-valued parameter. Table-valued parameters are input-only; the OUTPUT keyword is not supported. " I can not use the OUTPUT keyword. Or am I misinterpreting your suggestion ?

Comment: The OUTPUT clause returns data as a normal result set as if you hat written SELECT. You can read that result set using the normal APIs like IDataReader. Because you cannot directly return data in the TVP you need to somehow correlate OUTPUT rows with the inserted rows in the TVP so that you know which ID belongs to which inserted row. You could do that using some kind of sequence number or Guid's.

Comment: Ok thank you for the respond, It helped me a lot. Because of an (business logic) implication I could not use the 'MERGE' statement. But it was very useful to get to my end result with some work arounds. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Do the SqlBulkCopy with table lock so that other threads can't mess with your data
2. Generate the query in code => I know many projects that do this and this seems to be acceptable for bulk inserts...
3. usr's answer, use TVP and correlate the ids with a custom generated number
4. Switch to GUIDs for your id's (a DBA will kill you for this :-P)

Good luck!